# what is the benefit to use Q defer?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am new in Q. lib

When do we need to use Q.defer ?

what is the benefit?

can we return promise with q.defer?

```
 var deferred = Q.defer();
FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", function (error, text) {
if (error) {
    deferred.reject(new Error(error));
} else {
    deferred.resolve(text);
}
 });
  return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: What part of the documentation don't you understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**How do I convert an existing callback API to promises**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main authors of the Q library has written [an article](https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/) stating that `Q.defer()` is unnatural and outdated (although it does still have some practical applications).

The more modern approach (which is what the article is about) is the *revealing constructor pattern*. This is also the approach that is in the ES6 Promise standard (`defer` is not included in the standard), so you are best off using that when it is available:

```
return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    FS.readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8", function (error, text) {
        if (error) {
            reject(new Error(error));
        } else {
            resolve(text);
        }
    });
});
```

But to get to (what I think is) the gist of your question, both `Q.defer()` and the above pattern are useful when you want to create a promise from an Async API that does not produce promises. If you use promises in your code, it's a good idea to use promises for all of your async code rather than mixing and matching. The `Q.Promise()` constructor and `Q.defer()` allow you to bridge that gap.

**Note:** Since you are working with a Node-style API, there is a simpler technique designed specifically for this. You can use `Q.nfbind` to convert a node-style async function into a function that returns promises:

```
var readFile = Q.nfbind(FS.readFile);

readFile("foo.txt", "utf-8").then(function (data) {
    console.log("Got the file!");
});
```